# Regex construction

Tags: regex

I've large text file(Input) and I need to find the following sentence in the input.

```
HTTP REFERER gsp
```

I could not get this right!. Here is my regex(which is not correct).

```
([A-Z])\w+\s+[a-zA-Z]
```

Can you please tell me whats wrong with the above regex.

Comment: You need to write a regex that does what? you provided the input - and you should provide the expected output as well.

Comment: @alfasin!. It should give the output as this sentence.
HTTP REFERER gsp

Comment: Then have the sentence as your regex...

Comment: Okay. Here is the final one.
^[HTTP]+\s[REFERER]+\s[gsp]+$              (verified in rubular)

Thank you @alfasin.

Comment: No, I meant literally: use the regex: `^HTTP REFERER gsp$`

Comment: you can try `/HTTP REFERER gsp/` :-D

Comment: try `([A-Z])\w+(?:\s+[a-zA-Z]+)+`

Comment: What language/ tool are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's find out why your line is wrong to begin with, then it will be easier to come up with a correct line on your own in the future. You have the following line:

```
([A-Z])\w+\s+[a-zA-Z]
```

First, let's presume that you're embracing this line with the standard forward slash that begins and ends all RegExs.

Second, the `()`'s you're using do nothing. You don't need to put them around `[]`'s.

Third, the use of both A-Z and a-z should be avoided by adding the case insensitive flag `i` right after the closing `/` of the RegEx. Your expression should be looking like this by now:

```
/[A-Z]\w+\s+[A-Z]/i
```

Fourth, the \w is the flag for upper/lower case letters, numbers, and the _. Essentially everything except punctuation and spaces. The + after the \w groups the 'word' characters after it over and over until it hits something that is a space or a punctuation and makes this one group.

Fifth, the \s handles all white space and the + continues to group any infinite amount of occurrences of white space into the same group, until it hits something that isn't a space.

Sixth, the [A-Z] is checking for ONE character only of any uppercase letter.

Seventh, the /i at the end of the expression makes everything prior case insensitive.

Therefore, you can see that in the following searched statement: 
HTTP REFERER gsp

That right now you'd only highlight/group the following:
`HTTP REFERER g` sp

Why doesn't it highlight the 'sp' like what you were thinking? Well, the last part of your expression only looks for one occurrence of an upper case letter. Here are some solutions to consider:

```
/[A-Z]\w+\s+[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]/i
```

This gives the 3 occurrences at the end you're looking for. But probably not the most "eloquent" RegEx I've seen.

You could append {3} onto the end of the bracket, which will repeat the preceding element however by the number you put in the bracket. So you could have:

```
/[A-Z]\w+\s+[A-Z]{3}/i
```

This looks a bit nicer and allows you to stay probably very close to the exact pattern you're matching.

Now go back, and think about the uselessness of the first [A-Z]. It says "look for SINGLE letter, and then look for \w+, which is just any amount of letters after."

It's redundant, and the fact that I saw you first put a [A-Z]\w+ told me immediately that you were a little confused about this. So, to finally write your statement, I'd have it look like:

```
/\w+\s+[A-Z]{3}/i
```

Hopefully this makes total sense, but if not, please leave a comment and I'll elaborate!